# Laravel4 Validator, Captcha, & Session unable to match

Tags: php, session, laravel-4, captcha

I have a helper method that returns a captcha image url & stores a session of the key:

```
function captcha(){
  $builder = new CaptchaBuilder;
  $builder->build();
  Session::put('phrase', $builder->getPhrase());

  return $builder->inline();
}
```

The user then writes the captcha and submits the form and my controller grabs all and validates it:

```
'captcha' => 'required|same:'.Session::get('phrase')
```

The problem is no-matter what it always says they phrase & the textbox submission are not the same...
I can give more information if needed, also if this is not the best way to do it please give me suggestions, I am just learning Laravel4.

*Edit for some output info:*

If I return the values from the controller:

```
return "Session:".Session::get('phrase')." - Input:".$input['captcha'];
```

It returns: `Session:5zij5 - Input:5zij5`

Comment: Have you compared `Session::get('phrase')` and `Input::get('captcha')`? Is it possible that the phrase session is getting overwritten on each page load, before the form data is handled?

Comment: I updated my post to answer your question. Everything is how its suppose too. The issue lies in the same:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Laravel's docs, `same` refers to another input.

I'd recommend using a [custom validation rule](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules) to compare the session and the input.